# How to connect Jquery to Database in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel

I'm learning to write web on Laravel, but I still don't know how to connect jquery to database MySql,I want to know how to pass 1 or 0 to database. so I need some advice from anyone who knows.
I'm sorry, my English grammar is not good.

What I have written at the outset is as follows:

HTML:

```
<form action="{{ route('dashboard.update', $value->id) }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   {{ $value->port_1 }}
   @if ($value->port_1 == 1)
   <div>
       <label class="switch">
           <input id = "port_{{$value->id}}" data-id="{{$value->id}}" onchange=myFunction({{$value->id}}) value = {{$value->port_1}} class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $value->port_1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
           <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    @else
    <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input id = "port_{{$value->id}}" data-id="{{$value->id}}" onchange=myFunction({{$value->id}}) value = {{$value->port_1}} class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $value->port_1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
             <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
     </div>
     @endif
 </form>
```

Jquery:

```
function myFunction(id) {

var value = document.getElementById("port_" + id).value;

if (value == 1) {
    document.getElementById("port_" + id).value = 0;
    //alert(document.getElementById("port_" + id).value);
}
if (value == 0) {
    document.getElementById("port_" + id).value = 1;
    //alert(document.getElementById("port_" + id).value);
}

var port_id = id;
var newPermLevel = document.getElementById("port_" + id).value;

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/dashboard/update/' + port_id,
    data: {
        'port_id': port_id,
        'value': value,
        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',

    },

    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Ajax success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        alert("Ajax error");
    }
});
```

}

Controller (CRUD system in the update function):

```
public function update(Request $request, Dashboard $dashboard)
{
    //
    $request->validate([
        'id' => '',
        'port_1'  => 'required'
    ]);

    $dashboard->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index')
                     ->with('success', 'Post update successfully.');
}
```

It's a switch button, pass 1 or 0 to the database.
Please give me advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: The only database jquery can connect to is couchdb afaik.

Comment: Where/how do you send data to your controller? jquery is client-side, Laravel/database is server-side, you'd need AJAX to send data

Comment: You cannot connect jquery with database directly. As database will be on server, you can send request to laravel to access database.